# How to change payment state programmatically?

Tags: 8, commerce, payment-gateways, page-controller

I had created a custom module to update order state and payment state. In my controller I used the following code to change the order state of order.

```
 $order = \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order::load($order_id);

 if ($payment_status === 'payment.captured'){
   $order->set('state', 'completed');
   $order->save();
 }
 else {
   $order->set('state', 'pending');
   $order->save();
 }
```

**How can I now change the payment state of a payment which comes inside that order?**

This is the screenshot of my payment. Now the payment state is pending. I want to change it to something else by using code, for example completed.

[image: This is the screenshot of my payment. Now the payment state is pending , I want to change it to something else by using code,for example completed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clive method doesn't work, probably he wanted to write

```
 $payments = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_payment')->loadByProperties(['order_id' => $order->id()]);
```

the other method would be to load it with loadMultiple

```
$payments = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_payment')->loadMultipleByOrder($order);
```

also @Interdruper method works and is slimmer as it first loads ids and not whole payments.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
use Drupal\commerce_payment\Entity\Payment;

$payments = \Drupal::entityQuery('commerce_payment')
  ->condition('order_id', $order->id())
  ->execute();

foreach ($payments as $value) {
  $payment = Payment::load($value);
  $payment->setState('completed')->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load up the payments:

```
$payments = \Drupal\commerce_order\Payment\Payment::loadByProperties(['order_id' => $order->id()]);
```

Then loop through and save what you want to:

```
foreach ($payments as $payment) {
  $payment->setState('completed')->save();
}
```

Comment: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Class 'Drupal\commerce_order\Payment\Payment' not found in Drupal\razorpay\Controller\RazorpayController->hook() (line 36 of modules/custom/razorpay/src/Controller/RazorpayController.php).

Comment: Above is definitely not working (anymore),